# Which command gets udevdb.txt file at launchpad?

Tags: command-line, launchpad, udev, apport

When I run `ubuntu-bug` or `apport-collect` an `udevdb.txt` file listing all devices is uploaded to Launchpad.

How can I get this file without using Launchpad?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command used by Apport is: `udevadm info --export-db`

See the `attach_hardware` function in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/hookutils.py`.  It does a bit of anonymisation of partition labels as well, but that's not important if you're just going to analyse the output locally.

Answer (score 3):

I have never used `apport-collect` but from the `man` pages you can use `apport-cli` to get what you want:

```
apport-cli [ --save file ]
```

Excerpt from `man apport-cli`:

> --save filename

```
          In  --file-bug  mode, save the collected information into a file
          instead of reporting it. This file can  then  be  reported  with
          --crash-file later on.
```

Usage:

```
apport-cli [ --save file ] symptom | pid | package | program path | .apport/.crash file
```

Comment: I'll try this. But I wanted the bash command, probably `udevadm` with some params that gets this file. It is somewhere in the apport code.